# Using golangs regex for parsing sports score

Tags: regex, go

I'm trying use golang regex for parsing sports score, but can't found a reason, why it doesn't parse all scores parts, but only the first and the last.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {
    var FirstQuarterBasketballRegexp = regexp.MustCompile(`^(\d+:\d+)\s\((?:(\d+:\d+)(?:,\s)?)+\)$`)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", FirstQuarterBasketballRegexp.FindAllStringSubmatch("102:72 (28:17, 27:15, 24:14, 23:26)", -1))
}
```

It prints a string

```
[["102:72 (28:17, 27:15, 24:14, 23:26)" "102:72" "23:26"]]
```

Why it contains only 3 elem in a slice?

Comment: What do you want it to match? (also, why are you using a regex for this?)

Comment: I want to validate score and get all scores part at the same time. So, i search the same output as (\d+:\d+) as stribizhev said.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It returns 3 elements, as there is 0th group (the whole string), and 2 capturing groups:

```
1.  [0-6]   `102:72`
2.  [29-34] `23:26`
```

Now, you should think about what you need, and only use what you need.

Perhaps, you are looking for `(\d+:\d+)` that will return

```
102:72
28:17
27:15
24:14
23:26
```

Try this code ([sample program is available here](http://goo.gl/JwrO5g)):

```
func main() {
    var FirstQuarterBasketballRegexp = regexp.MustCompile(`\d+:\d+`)
    fmt.Printf("%q\n", FirstQuarterBasketballRegexp.FindAllStringSubmatch("102:72 (28:17, 27:15, 24:14, 23:26)", -1))
}
```

Output:

```
[["102:72"] ["28:17"] ["27:15"] ["24:14"] ["23:26"]]
```

Comment: Is it possible to validate scores string and get the result at the same time?

Comment: To validate, you should provide rules for validation. Actually, you asked about something else. I suggest posting another question after trying to solve that all by yourself first. On SO, we value people's own efforts.

Comment: I probably misunderstood regex. Think it should return [["102:72 (28:17, 27:15, 24:14, 23:26)" "102:72" "27:15" "24:14" "23:26"]] if score like "102:72 (28:17, 27:15, 24:14, 23:26)" and return empty slice if score like "70:70 (14:23, 21:21, 18:14, 17:12 overtime 5:9)"